# Using clipboard in Overleaf: how to keep the output cliboard?

Tags: overleaf, clipboard

I am trying to use package `clipboard` to copy/paste within two documents, and using Overleaf. The problem is that Overleaf is not saving the output of `\newclipboard{myclipboard}`, and hence running `\openclipboard{myclipboard}` in the second document results into an error

> File `myclipboard.cpy' not found

How do I make sure that Overleaf keeps the `myclipboard.cpy` created?

Reproducible example taken from copy/paste in [this](https://texnical-designs.com/copy-and-paste-with-the-latex-clipboard-package/) page:

File 1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{clipboard}

\newclipboard{myclipboard}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\Copy{Einstein}{We cannot solve our problems with the same thinking we used when we created them. \\
Albert Einstein}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

File 2:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{clipboard}
\openclipboard{myclipboard}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{quote}
\Paste{Einstein}
\end{quote}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Getting in touch with Overleaf Support (support@overleaf.com) for Overleaf-related questions is recommended (I'm on the support team, and we are happy to help).

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer thanks to the Overleaf support. One just needs to save the clipboard with prefix `output-` (say `output-myclipboard`). There is an internal convention that such files will not be overridden when compiling the second document.

As a side note, another solution is to use the same approach to handle the `xr` package (see [documentation](https://fr.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf)). It is, however, more complicated, and does not allow to compile twice the auxiliary document (i.e. one would need to compile every time the main before compiling the auxiliary).